# Backslash character in the json

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I receive from the server requests as:

- `{"name": "text \"Home\""}`
- `{"name": "A/A\A"}`

I have to keep this format, and convert them to JSON.

Tried :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper() 
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(request);
```

First example converts well, but the second fails because of `\A`. Also tried:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()                .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS.mappedFeature());
```

In this case `\` removed from the `"A/A\A"` and the result is `"A/AA"` what I don't want.

Also tried:

```
request.replace("\\", "\\\\ֿֿֿֿ");
```

and after that converting the request again, but in this case first example failed to convert.

Any idea/library/tools how to keep these backslashes as an original request?

Comment: `{"name": "A/A\A"}` is invalid JSON. The solution here is to fix the source of the data, making it produce valid JSON. Anything else is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Please note that "library/tools" recommendation requests are specifically off-topic for SO. (Asking for solutions, which you also do in that sentence, is fine.)